# Migrating js based ko.bindingHandler to typescript for JQuery.DataTables, NodeType & parentNode does not exist

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, datatables

I am trying to use a [ko.bindingHandler that someone else made to enable the use of JQuery.Datatables with Knockout](https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/comment/109479/#Comment_109479) but I am also using typescript and very green with all of these technologies.

The problems are that nodeType and parentNode types are not known.

```
                var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
                    if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                    }
                });
                return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            }
```

How can I change this code so that it will work with typescript? It seems that the problem is not that I'm missing a type definition file but that there is a different syntax I should follow.

Comment: Try declaring the type of the node variable. `ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node: Node) {`

Comment: errors went away! but the site still won't launch, could very possibly be an unrelated issue, investigating...